# How to fix 'zoom' icon issue with LightGallery

Tags: html, css, lightgallery

I'm using LightGallery (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/), I have insert all required files and CSS. It is working fine with full screen, but I want to enable the MouseOver zoom icon over the photos before open the full screen.

But I'm not able to get zoom icon with MouseOver event.

- This is what I get

[image: This is what I get]

- This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#aniimated-thumbnials').lightGallery({
        thumbnail: true,
        animateThumb: true,
        showThumbByDefault: true
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="aniimated-thumbnials" class="list-unstyled">
 <a class="jg-entry" href="img/ProductGallery/Gallery_images1.png" data-sub-html="sdsdsd">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ProductGallery/Gallery_images1_thumb.png">
  <div class="">
   <img src="img/zoom.png" />
  </div>
  
 </a>
 <a class="jg-entry" href="img/ProductGallery/Gallery_images2.png" data-sub-html="sdsdsd">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ProductGallery/Gallery_images2_thumb.png">
  <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
   <img src="img/zoom.png" />
  </div>
  
 </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: first thing: in your demo, the 'demo-gallery-poster' class is missing on gallery image 1.

Comment: Second: you forgot to post your CSS code, which is responsible for the position of the zoom icon.
Did you compare your CSS code with the one from here? https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same "issue". In reality, it's not really an issue with the lightGallery plugin as it's not a feature they're offering. In their demo, zoom icon is just a feature they've put together for the demo and is not offered WITH the plugin.

So I had to look at their source code to be able to do this.

Below is the CSS you need to add, and remember that you also need to have your image in the same DOM level as your `demo-gallery-poster` class, both inside an `a`. The same way you're doing it.

```
a:hover .demo-gallery-poster>img {
  opacity: 1;
}

a .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}

a .demo-gallery-poster>img {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

a>img {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover>img {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}

a:hover .demo-gallery-poster>img {
  opacity: 1;
}

a .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
}

a .demo-gallery-poster>img {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.demo-gallery .video .demo-gallery-poster img {
  height: 48px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 48px;
}
```